# How to validate some of the inputs in my component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to `reactjs`. I'm creating a contactlist sample with `reactjs` and fetching data from api. how to validate name and phone number in add contact and edit contact.

My objective is:

1. In name field only letters should be accepted
2. In phone Number field - numbers should be accepted. if the number already exist in contactlist data then it should show number already exist.

JSON data:

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "name":"ABC",
      "phone":"1234567890"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "name":"DEF",
      "phone":"9978456313"
   }
]
```

Component:

```
class AddContact extends Component{

constructor(){
super();
this.state = {name: '', phone:''}
}

changeHandler  = e => {
this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}

handleSubmit = e => {

const item={name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone}
 fetch('api/contacts', {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(() => {
          this.props.history.push('/contact');
        });

}
render(){

return(

         <Form>
                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Name"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={item.firstname}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />

                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Phone Number"
                    type="number"
                    name="phone"
                    value={item.phone}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />
                  <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    label="Email"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={item.email}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  />
              </Form>

<Button inverted color='teal' onClick={this.handleSubmit} className='saveContactbtn'>Save</Button>

);
}
}

export default AddContact;
```

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: For a start, you could validate the user entered values in the `changeHandler` function.

Comment: @Ramesh - Can you tell me briefly?

Comment: @Ramesh - If i wont give phone number and click on save then it is not showing any error. Even not showing the data in the contactlist

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding two methods to perform validation checks on the number and name provided:

```
isValidName = name => { 
   // perform checks 
   // returns true if name is valid, else false  
}

isValidNumber = number => { 
   // perform checks 
   // returns true if number is valid, else false  
}

contactNotDuplicate = number => {
     // Return a promise which will GET current list, and resolve if 
     // contact unique, reject if it is duplicate.     
}
```

Finally, perform the check for valid name and number first, if all good then check for duplicate number before the POST in the `handleSubmit` method:

```
handleSubmit = e => {     
    if(this.isValidName(this.state.name) && 
       this.isValidNumber(this.state.phone)){
       this.contactNotDuplicate(this.state.phone)
        .then(() => {
          const item={name: this.state.name, phone: this.state.phone};

          fetch('api/contacts', {
              method: 'POST', 
              body: JSON.stringify(item),
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(() => {
            this.props.history.push('/contact');
          });
       })
        .catch(() => /* display duplicate error to user */);    
    }               
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me what to give in `isValidName` method, So that i could get some idea to write for the remaining methods